# Practical differences between "do {...} while (0)" and "{...} ((void)0)" in macros?

Tags: c, syntax, macros

It's common practice in C to use:

```
#define FOO() do { /* body */ } while (0)
```

While this is fine, it's also possible to do:

```
#define FOO() { /* body */ }((void)0)
```

---

`{...}((void)0)` has many of the same benefits: you can't accidentally merge logic, and a `;` is required at the end of the line, so odd expressions like this don't go by un-noticed: `FOO() else {...}`.

The *only* difference I've noticed is it means you need to use braces in if-statements.

```
if (a)
    FOO();
else
    BAR();
```

Must be written as:

```
if (a) {
    FOO();
} else {
    BAR();
}
```

Other then this quirk, it seems to work well, preventing the same kinds of problems `do/while` method is typically used for.

Are there any significant differences between the 2 methods?

*Said differently*, if you see a code-base using `{...}((void)0)`, are practical reasons to switch to using `do{..}while(0)`, besides the one difference already noted?

Comment: The `{ … } (void)0` variant is never used in practice — I've never seen it suggested before, even.  It is plain _weird_!  And pointless.  And useless, because you can't use it as simply as the `do { … } while (0)` alternative.  The `(void)0` cast buys you precisely nothing of value — it is devoid of benefit.

Comment: Practical difference #1: people know and recognize the `do { ... } while(0)` variant, and not the other.

Comment: The difference you pointed out is huge.

Comment: @xxbbcc, `{ ... }(void)0` and `if (1) { ... } else` are completely different.

Comment: @ideasman42: You're right. It will produce an error message. I take it back. But it still strikes me as a bad idea.

Comment: I agree, `(void)0` does not force a semicolon next.

Comment: @Ben Voigt , `(void)0` does force a semicolon next (with clang and gcc at least)

Comment: @ideasman42: No, the grammar does not require a semicolon next.  See http://rextester.com/KJLA9675

Comment: Can you show an example of `{}(void)0` used without a terminating semicolon? (`void func() { (void)0 }` -> `error: expected ';' before '}' token`)

Comment: I linked an example right there in my comment.  It would have been an answer, but the question got closed, so I edited the comment.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, excellent point, would be a good answer to the question in-fact.

Comment: @Ben Voigt, the example you linked uses C++, I managed to use the comma operator `void func() { FOO(), call(); }` which is disallowed if `while(0)` is used. But this is not so different from C regular syntax, where you can do 2 statements too `func(), func();`

Comment: Same example works fine in C: http://rextester.com/ADOSK79081

Comment: @Ben Voigt, in this case `{ ... } ((void)0)` solves the problem. updated the question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler do...while(0) is weird too, it's just that we are used to this weird :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The practical difference is exactly what you pointed out.

The `do { ... } while (0)` idiom means that the macro can be used in *any* context that requires a statement.

Your suggested idiom `{ ... } ((void)0)` can be used safely in *most* contexts that require an expression -- but it can fail if it's used in an unbraced `if` statement.

I can think of no good reason to use an unfamiliar idiom that *almost* always works, when there's a well known idiom that *always* works.

Comment: Theres one case it doesn't work - when you want to use a `break` within the macro, (admittedly not something which is done often though).

Answer (score 2):

One difference is you can use break with `#define FOO() do { /* body */ } while (0)` but not with `#define FOO() { /* body */ }(void)0`.

Let's say you are inside a function, say `hello()`, and doing something in `#define FOO() do { /*some device operation */ } while (0)` but some error occurred so you no longer want to proceed with that device but there are other statements in function `hello()` you want to execute, let's say for another device.

So if you use second statement then you will do return most probably which will exit out of `hello()` but if you use the first statement you can happily `break` and do some operation in same function `hello()` for another device.

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a compelling difference.  You can code the body so that instead of `if (condition) break; …rest of body…` you write `if (!condition) { …rest of body… }`.  That's an essentially trivial change.  You could even embed a `do ... while (0)` inside the `{ …here… } (void)0` version.

Comment: Posting an example :)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler how about multiple if condition ? though you can always code but will be readable ? like this http://ideone.com/wfC6Ib

Comment: ok see this link if it convince you. but one reason for choosing one over the other is that. It makes things much more simpler to read and write

Comment: Which link?  And are you actually posting an example, or am I misinterpreting what your comment meant.

Comment: that's the example in link that I have written because of limitation of words in comment

Comment: Oh, you mean the link http://ideone.com/wfC6Ib in a previous comment?  Sorry; didn't notice that.  I think it means you added the link after I saw the comment and responded.  I'd need to see what the macros `communicate` and `call` expand to, since they don't leave valid code when they are written as shown on ideone.  But there's no visible reason to be using the `FOO` macro; it has no parameters, so it could be a (possibly `inline`) function instead, which would be a lot cleaner and clearer.  Put succinctly, that example does not change my mind.

Comment: One of the reasons I was considering `{...}((void)0)` is precisely because its not allowing for `break` statements.